# Django filter a queryset in a template

Tags: django

I know this is not recommended as it should be done in the view, but i have a scenario whereby I need to filter within template.

I have sitefiles_set which I request 2 or 3 times within the same template and use if statements to show the right filetypes in the right place. (its all a display thing)

so in my template for a particular file type (photos) below, ive split the data up into table columns to make it more readable in the page. However the template forloop counter counts all files, not just the ones in the if, so in my actually display, i have 5 links displayed in the left column, then 8 links in the right.

so i need to filter out those that are not cabinet photos instead of using an if. but i need the model the same so i can use it again in another section to show another type.

Thanks

```
<b>Cabinet Photos:</b><br/>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <ul class="standard-list">
                                {% for file in Site.sitefiles_set.all %}
                                    {% if file.file_type.type == 'Cabinet Photo' %}
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.site_image }}" data-lightbox="sitephotos" data-title="{{ file.file_name }}">
                                            {{ file.file_name }}
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"8" and file.file_type.type == 'Cabinet Photo' %}
                                                </ul>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <ul class="standard-list">
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"16" and file.file_type.type == 'Cabinet Photo' %}
                                                </ul>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <ul class="standard-list">
                                        {% endif %} 
                                    {% endif %}                                     
                                {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: you should use a template tag then

Comment: @MosesKoledoye how do i do this?

Comment: use templatetag filter with |

Comment: could you show me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i did it with this

```
from django import template
from networks.models import SiteFiles

register = template.Library()

@register.assignment_tag
def get_files_by_type(SiteFiles, type):
    return SiteFiles.filter(file_type__type=type)
```